# How to create a customized filter search function in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-filter

I am trying to create a filter search bar that I can customize. For example, if I type a value into a search bar, then it will query a model and retrieve a list of instances that match the value. For example, here is a view:

```
class StudentListView(FilterView):
    template_name = "leads/student_list.html"
    context_object_name = "leads"
    filterset_class = StudentFilter

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Lead.objects.all()
```

and here is my filters.py:
class

```
StudentFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    class Meta:
        model = Lead
        fields = {
            'first_name': ['icontains'],
            'email': ['exact'],
        }
```

Until now, I can only create a filter search bar that can provide a list of instances that match `first_name` or `email`(which are fields in the `Lead` model). However, this does now allow me to do more complicated tasks. Lets say I added `time` to the filter fields, and I would like to not only filter the `Lead` model with the `time` value I submitted, but also other `Lead` instances that have a `time` value that is near the one I submitted. Basically, I want something like the `def form_valid()` used in the views where I can query, calculate, and even alter the values submitted.

Moreover, if possible, I would like to create a filter field that is not necessarily an actual field in a model. Then, I would like to use the submitted value to do some calculations as I filter for the list of instances. If you have any questions, please ask me in the comments. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do just about anything by defining a method on the filterset to map the user's input onto a queryset. Here's one I did earlier. Code much cut down ...

The filter `coat_info_contains` is defined as a `CharFilter`, but it is further parsed by the method which splits it into a set of substrings separated by commas. These substrings are then used to generate `Q` elements (OR logic) to match a model if the substring is contained in any of three model fields `coating_1`, `coating_2` and `coating_3`

This filter is not implicitly connected to any particular model field. The connection is through the `method=` specification of the filter to the filterset's method, which can return absolutely any queryset on the model that can be programmed.

Hope I haven't cut out anything vital.

```
import django_filters as FD

class MemFilter( FD.FilterSet): 

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel

       # fields = [fieldname, ... ] # default filters created for these. Not required if all declarative.
        # fields = { fieldname: [lookup_expr_1, ...], ...}  # for specifying possibly multiple lookup expressions
        fields = { 
             'ft':['gte','lte','exact'], 'mt':['gte','lte','exact'],
               ...            
            }

    # declarative filters. Lots and lots of
    ...
    coat_info_contains = FD.CharFilter( field_name='coating_1',
        label='Coatings contain',
        method='filter_coatings_contains' 
    )
    ...

    def filter_coatings_contains( self, qs, name, value):
        values = value.split(',')
        qlist = []
        for v in values:
            qlist.append( 
                Q(coating_1__icontains = v) |
                Q(coating_2__icontains = v) |
                Q(coating_3__icontains = v) )
        return qs.filter( *qlist )
```